# Getting Currently Viewed User Profile

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, lightning-community

I was wondering if there was a way to get certain information of a currently viewed User Profile in APEX?

Here's a sample scenario: 
1. I have a community page with a Group List 
2. I go into a Group, then I click on a User on the Group. 
3. While viewing that particular User, I wanted to manipulate certain data in my component based on currently viewed User.

Update:

Adding a reference image as to which User Profile I am talking about.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Profile Id and other info about the running user with the [`UserInfo`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) class. If you want to know the Profile Id of the currently logged in user, use `UserInfo.getProfileId();`

If you want to know about some other user you can query the `User` sobject:

```
select id,.. from user where id =: userId
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This class seems to return UserInfo about the context user. I think that means, the user who is currently viewing the community, yes?  I was hoping to get the user info of the currently viewed user profile not the current user profile.

Comment: what is url of community when you are viewing a user?

Comment: the url of the community for viewing a user profile looks something like this: https://mycommunity.developer-edition.na3.force.com/mycommunitysample/s/profile/005500000067Om3AAE please note this url doesn't actually work.